# React hash router how to get current path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My react router code is like this.

```
render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <DesignerHeader currentPath={} >
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/"
              render={() => <Redirect to={ROUTE_PATH.TRANSACTION_LIST} />
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path='/Subject'
              render={(props) => <DesignerWithSubject {...props} />
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path='/Designer'
              render={(props) => <Designer {...props} />
              }
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path='/Name'
              render={(props) => <DesignerWithName {...props} />
              }
            />                           
          </Switch>
        </DesignerHeader>

      </HashRouter>
    )}
```

In this I have to currentPath to DesignerHeader how i can approach that?
i am using react router 4.

Comment: `DesignerHeader` doesn't match its closing tag `DesignerAppLayout`, is this just a typo in this example?

Comment: Thanks it is just typo . corrected

Comment: Have you tried to use this.props.location.pathname? If you have no location in your props you can export the DesignHeader with with "withRouter": export default withRouter(DesignerHeader). So designerHeader will have all the props ad a normal Route.

Comment: Thanks @PaoloDell'Aguzzo that solve my problem.